# Use the Desktop's SSD to run an OS on notebook without losing the current data and OS setup

Tags: boot, ssd

I need to try to use 1 hard disk - which already has a Windows 7 installation on Desktop -n a notebook. Disk is not divided and only have 40 gb free space.

What I want is

1. Unplug SSD from desktop, plug it  to notebook. Install an OS there (which I can delete manually later), see it works.
2. Unplug it from notebook, plug it to desktop. Open Win 7, Delete other OS's files. Get rid of boot sequence so Windows 7 can boot alone with no extra key pressing.

Is it doable? If yes how?

Also if possible can i trick the notebook to boot The Windows 7 installed on Desktop? This will make this very less time consuming.

Goal: Use the Desktop's SSD to run an OS on notebook *without* losing the current data and OS setup.

Comment: Why my question is getting negative points?

Comment: probably because, apart from it being likely unfeasible, I don't think anyone's quite sure what you're asking… swap drives, add an OS, swap again, delete an OS, add another OS, expect it to boot 2 machines? Short answer, no.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is doable but need extra or special code and work at worst case.
Possible solutions.
1-An advanced partition program that can divide disk to logical 2 parts without destroying the data.
2-An advanded booter that can boot different OS from the same harddrive without any need of partitioning.
3-Re-install/upgrade Windows 7 on both computers every time to use the harddrive in one of them.

Comment: Picture the scene: You make a generic boot drive, quite possible for installing to a bare metal machine. You put this in machine one. It installs the necessary drivers & makes you reboot. It then demands you reauthorise Windows. You then put this drive in another machine… all the drivers are now wrong & it again wants you to reauthorise Windows. Repeat ad nauseum.

Comment: Maybe if you tell us what you are trying to accomplish (not how to do it), we can offer solutions that might work. As you've described, you can't plugin a hard drive from another computer to install an OS from that existing OS. You need installation media to do that. So, please clarify your end goal and maybe we can help.

Comment: After your edit - still not possible. It's possible to clone the existing drive to a new drive, leaving out some machine-specific components so you can then use that as a bare-metal install to the second machine, which which will then need the correct driver & Windows authorisation. 2 drives, 2 machines, one a clone of the other, works. 1 drive 2 machines, still not going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok If anyone needs to the same thing for any reason heres the answer.

1. I used "MiniTool Partition Wizard Home Edition" to partition my drive Split 20 GB to do the job.No data loss.
2. Install the SSD to the laptop. (I tested the Desktops OS just to see what will happen.  A quick BlueScreen(0.5 sec) then auto-restart is answer to it)
3. Install "Windows 7" on Laptop to the new 20 GB partition. It worked like a charm.
4. Put the SSD back to the Desktop. And Now I am writing this.

Now all i need is to get rid of the booter at the starter. Then i can merge the partition and my SSD state will be the same at the start(Or at least similar enough if you know what i mean :)